# Set text field cursor to top

Tags: html, css

I have a simple form, Problem is why the cursor of the third text field is in the middle?

I want to be in the top left of the text field.

[image]

Here is my `stylesheet`:

```
.largeTextField{
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid rgb( 186, 186, 186 );
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 330px;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead a `<input>` set a `<textarea>`

> `<input>` - single line (row)
>
> `<textarea>` - multiple lines (rows)

Answer (score 2):

Using `input` will cause the larger box to be used as a 1-line entry. You will need to define a `textarea` to allow multiple lines, like this:

```
<label>Content</label><br>
<textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="30"></textarea>
```

You can read more about `inputs` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input).